# can i set the width of fields in my datagrid?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

how can i tighten things up and make the fields not so wide so it can fit on a page without horizontal scrolling? i added css to a div but the field is still very long while the link text does wrap (in some browsers)

i am hopping for a .net way to get it to work in all browsers.

here is my terrible UI of my data grid
[image: bed looking grid]

here is my defined asp.net code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" CellPadding="4" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt"
    EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnRowCommand="gv_RowCommand"
    OnRowEditing="gv_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="gv_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound"
    OnRowDeleting="gv_RowDeleting" OnRowUpdating="gv_RowUpdating" ShowFooter="true"
    DataKeyNames="ProjectLinkId,LastUpdate" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="cbEdit" Text="Edit" Width="75px" Font-Size="8pt" CommandName="Edit" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="cbDelete" Text="Delete" Width="75px" Font-Size="8pt"
                                CommandName="Delete" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="cbUpdate" Text="Update" Width="75px" Font-Size="8pt"
                                CommandName="Update" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="cbCancel" Text="Cancel" Width="75px" Font-Size="8pt"
                                CommandName="Cancel" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="cbSave" Text="Insert" Width="75px" Font-Size="8pt"
                    CommandName="Save" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblLinkTypeText" Text='<%# Bind("LinkTypeText") %>'
                    CssClass="DefaultFont" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlLinkTypeCID" CssClass="DefaultFont" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ftrLinkTypeCID" CssClass="DefaultFont" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="URL">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div style="width:316px; word-wrap: break-word">
                    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lbURL" NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("URL") %>' Text='<%# Bind("URL") %>' Width="300" />
                </div>   
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtURL" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Bind("URL") %>'
                    CssClass="DefaultTextBox" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ftrURL" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Bind("URL") %>'
                    CssClass="DefaultTextBox" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div style="width:316px; word-wrap: break-word">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDescription" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' CssClass="DefaultFont"/>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDescription" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'
                    CssClass="DefaultTextBox" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ftrDescription" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'
                    CssClass="DefaultTextBox" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `ItemStyle` element to your `TemplateField`

Example:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemStyle Width="45%" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        ...
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: @kacalapy did you add the `<ItemStyle Width="45%" />` element in all your `TemplateField` elements changing the width percentage base on your desired width?

Comment: the link text behaves but there is much white space to the right and the field is just as large... that is to say only the text gets pushed in, not the field.

Comment: @kacalapy  you can also try setting the `width` propert of the `GridView` element to shrink the overall size of the grid view.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the width in the ItemTemplate for the URL column, since that seems to be the problem one. Try something like 100px instead of 316

Specifically, here:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <div style="width:316px; word-wrap: break-word">
   <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lbURL" NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("URL") %>' Text='<%#Bind("URL") %>' Width="300" />
   </div>   
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: the link itself got smaller but the field is still the same length.

Comment: Try changing the link length for the <asp: HyperLink... item from 300 down to 100 as well

Answer (score 0):

why dont you put a css class on it and control the width from the css file?

/** EDIT **/

you can do it inline or put a class with the cssClass="nameofcolumn" and then on the css file:

> .nameofcolumn{
>       width: 400px; }

Hope it helps!

Comment: what would the css look like to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variation

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemStyle CssClass="styled-column"></ItemStyle>
    <ItemTemplate>
       ...
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

css:

```
.styled-column {
    width: 300px;
}
```

renders as:

```
<td class="styled-column">
      ...          
</td>
```